# How to make same JSF Composite Component included multiple times to have its own javascript scope?

Tags: javascript, jsf, composite-component

I have a JSF composite component like this:

```
 <cc:implementation>
   <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
        <h:outputScript library="js" name="helper.js"/>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        if(typeof variables === "undefined"){
             var variables = {};
        }

        (function(){
            variables.formid = '#{cc.clientId}'; 
        })();
        </script>
    </div>
```

Value of `variables.formid` I'm using in a `helper.js` file. When I include this composite component only once, it's working like it should. When I include multiple composite components, every component receives the value of a last included composite component, how can I solve this issue?

Comment: the `variables` variable in the global javascript scope. Maybe you should define a map of variables for your components, like `variables[#{cc.clientId}].formid = #{cc.clientId}`

Comment: In cases like this, think of how you would solve this in plain html if you needed to include the script part multiple times.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are basically 2 ways.

1. Add kind of "register" function to `helper.js`, so that you can explicitly register it there, instead of letting it to search for composites.

   ```
   <h:outputScript name="js/helper.js" target="head" />
   <div id="#{cc.clientId}">
       ...
   </div>
   <h:outputScript>helper.register("#{cc.clientId}", { foo: "somevalue" });</h:outputScript>
   ```

   Options can be provided via a JS object as argument. This is also how a.o. PrimeFaces work with `PrimeFaces.cw()` function, whereby the "widget name" is also passed as an option.
2. Give the composite an unique style class like so:

   ```
   <h:outputScript name="js/helper.js" target="head" />
   <div id="#{cc.clientId}" class="your-foo-composite">
       ...
   </div>
   ```

   This way the `helper.js` can just collect them by class name during document ready.

   ```
   // Vanilla JS:
   var yourFooComposites = document.getElementsByClassName("your-foo-composite");

   // Or if you happen to use jQuery:
   var $yourFooComposites = $(".your-foo-composite");
   ```

   Options can be provided as [HTML5 data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) ([browser support is good these days](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset)).

   ```
   <div id="#{cc.clientId}" class="your-foo-composite" data-foo="somevalue">
   ```

   Which can be obtained as:

   ```
   // Vanilla JS:
   for (var i = 0; i < yourFooComposites.length; i++) {
       var yourFooComposite = yourFooComposites[i];
       var clientId = yourFooComposite.id;
       var dataFoo = yourFooComposite.dataset.foo;
       // ...
   }

   // Or if you happen to use jQuery:
   $yourFooComposites.each(function(index, yourFooComposite) {
       var $yourFooComposite = $(yourFooComposite);
       var clientId = $yourFooComposite.attr("id");
       var dataFoo = $yourFooComposite.data("foo");
       // ...
   });
   ```

   It also keeps your HTML output free of inline scripts.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, usage of "js" as library name as in your initial code is not good. Carefully read [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used) Also note that I added `target="head"` attribute to the `<h:outputScript>`. In case you're properly using JSF `<h:head>` component, it will let JSF autorelocate the script to the generated HTML `<head>` element.