# UIComponent getAttributes only gets last value from JSF

Tags: jsf, composite-component, ajax4jsf

I have a JSF 2.2 composite component which is used more than once on the same page.

```
@FacesComponent("myComponent")
public class MyComponent extends UIComponent {

    public void test() {
        System.out.printlin(getAttributes("value"));
    }
}
```

component xhtml:

```
<composite:interface componentType="myComponent">
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="true" type="java.lang.String" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="test" action="#{cc.test()}" execute="input" />

    <s:span id="input">
        <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" onclick="test()" />
    </s:span>
</composite:implementation>
```

page xhtml

```
<my:myComponent value="#{bean.value}" />  -- line 1
<my:myComponent value="#{bean2.value}" /> -- line 2
```

When I click on the first myComponent, it calls test() but prints the value of bean2.value instead of bean.value. If I remove line 2 then it prints bean.value. I thought that the call to getAttributes() would get the value for current composite component, but it seems that it is only getting the value for the last composite component on the page. Could someone explain to me how the attributes are supposed to work or what I am missing?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the component behaves this way? Are you absolutely sure that you aren't actually invoking the wrong a4j:jsFunction?

Comment: Once again, when you invoke `test()`, which one did you actually expect to invoke as there are multiple of them? In JavaScript, normally any value/function assigned to a variable would override any previously assigned value/function. This closely related question contains possibly the answer you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29124665

Comment: Thanks so much, BalusC. That was the problem. I appended an id parameter to the jsFunction name, and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, with id attribute appended to the jsFunction to distinguish it from other same components on the page:

```
<composite:interface componentType="myComponent">
    <composite:attribute name="id" type="java.lang.String" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="true" type="java.lang.String" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <a4j:jsFunction name="#{cc.attrs.id}test" action="#{cc.test()}" execute="input" />

    <s:span id="input">
        <h:inputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}" onclick="#{cc.attrs.id}test()" />
    </s:span>
</composite:implementation>
```